# All possible triangles in terms of edges in RCCP

Tags: graph-theory, triangles, searching

NB: This question was first posted in Stack Overflow, it has been moved here on suggestion.

I'm stuck on finding an efficient algorithm to the following problem:

Given a complete undirected graph G with n nodes, the objective is to find all possible triangles in G in terms of edge indexes.

For example, with n = 3:

- 1, 2, 3

With n = 4, there are 4 triangles:

- 1, 2, 4
- 1, 3, 5
- 2, 3, 6
- 4, 5, 6

So the final triangle consists of edges nr 4, 5 and 6.

Currently my solution is quite inefficient, it works by calculating all 3-combinations to find triangles, and all 2-combinations to find pairs of nodes. Then I iterate over each triangle and search for the correct pairs and report the indexes.

Here is my current solution in RCPP:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix getallTriangles(size_t& n) {
  IntegerVector vals = seq(0, n-1);
  
  // comb_n() works as R's utils::combn()
  IntegerMatrix edges = comb_n(vals, 2);
  IntegerMatrix triangles = comb_n(vals, 3);
  
  size_t nEdges = edges.ncol();
  size_t nTriangles = triangles.ncol();
  
  // Output matrix
  IntegerMatrix out(3, nTriangles);

  for(size_t i = 0; i < nTriangles; i++) {
      
    IntegerVector triangle = triangles(_, i);
    // Get all edges in this triangle
    IntegerMatrix triangleCombn = comb_n(triangle, 2);
    
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      
      // Take an edge from the triangle
      IntegerMatrix::Column col = triangleCombn(_, j);
      
      // And compare it to all known edges
      for(size_t k = 0; k < nEdges; k++) {
        
        IntegerMatrix::Column edge = edges(_, k);
        
        if(col[0] == edge[0] && col[1] == edge[1]) {
            // We have found the edge
            out(j, i) = k + 1;
            // Stop searching
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  return out;
}
```

Calling this function in R:

```
> getallTriangles(4)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    4
[2,]    2    3    3    5
[3,]    4    5    6    6
```

My gut says there has got to be a better way to do this, or is there really no better solution than to do a search?

***EDIT***

Based on the answers given below, here is a working rcpp version:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerMatrix getallTriangles(size_t& n) {
  
  IntegerVector vals = seq(1, n);
  IntegerMatrix triangles = comb_n(vals, 3);
  
  size_t nTriangles = triangles.ncol();
  
  // Output matrix
  IntegerMatrix out(3, nTriangles);
  
  for(size_t i = 0; i < nTriangles; i++) {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      for(size_t k = j + 1; k < 3; k++) {

        // Take an edge from the triangle
        size_t a = triangles(j, i);
        size_t b = triangles(k, i);
        
        out(j + k - 1, i) = (a - 1) * n - a * (a + 1) / 2 + b;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return out;
}
```

Maybe this will be of use to someone.

Cheers

Comment: Is the graph a complete graph (i.e. is there an edge joining each pairs of nodes/vertices)?  If so, there are ${n \choose 3}$ triangles: just choose $3$ nodes/vertices and the corresponding three edges from a triangle.  How are the edges labelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* I understand what you're doing, but I'm not fully sure, so let's start with a description of what I think the problem is.

> you have a complete graph $K_n$, with nodes numbered from 1-n, and edges numbered in lexicographic order based on their two end nodes.  You seek all the triangles in the graph, given as a list of edges.

You already have it set up to give you the triangles as `comb_n(vals, 3)`, so I'll skip that part and get to the meat: you need to find the edge, based on the nodes, without a long search.

Fortunately, this isn't hard.  Given two node indices $a < b$:

$$e = \frac{n \times (n-1)}{2} - \frac{(n-a)\times(n-a+1)}{2}+b-a=an-n-\frac{a^2}{2}-\frac{a}{2}+b$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Dan! This has been bothering me for 2 weeks now, slowing down my code :-).

PS. I have edited my question to be more clear about the graph for posterity

Comment: Hi Dan, would it be possible to add further clarification on why the function you provide works? I'd love to get a better understanding of it. I recognize the first part as (n choose 2).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a complete graph (i.e. there is an edge joining each pair of nodes/vertices).  If so, there are ${n \choose 3}$ triangles: just choose $3$ nodes/vertices and the corresponding three edges from a triangle.  You seem to be using R's `combn` function to label the edges and triangles, starting at $1$ (you might find it easier to start counting vertices from $1$ too).

If so, the following R code works

```
verticestoedge <- function(a, b, n){   #presumes 1 <= a < b <= n
    (a - 1) * n - a * (a + 1) / 2 + b 
    }
alltriangleedges <- function(n){
    trianglevertices <- utils::combn(1:n, 3)
    rbind(verticestoedge(trianglevertices[1, ], trianglevertices[2, ], n), 
          verticestoedge(trianglevertices[1, ], trianglevertices[3, ], n), 
          verticestoedge(trianglevertices[2, ], trianglevertices[3, ], n))
    }
```

and for example

```
alltriangleedges(4)
```

gives

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    2    4
[2,]    2    3    3    5
[3,]    4    5    6    6
```

Now seeing Dan Uznanski's answer, his expression is the same as `verticestoedge` here

Comment: Thanks for the answer Henry, the reason I was using zero-indexing is because the switching between indexes in rcpp and R was a major source of bugs. I decided to just use 0 indexing everywhere to mitigate it.

Your code works great in R, I have added a rcpp version in my answer